# Comparing two arrays and not getting expected output in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have the following controller action that builds two arrays.

```
current_event = Event.find(params[:event_id])

campaign_titles = Relationship::CampaignTitleRelationship.where(campaign_id: current_event.campaign_id)

campaign_title_ids = Array.new

campaign_titles.each do |title|

  campaign_title_ids << [title.title_id]

end

event_title_ids = Array.new

params[:title_ids].each do |title|

  event_title_ids << [title]

end
```

The two arrays output like this

```
[["6556"], ["9359"], ["11319"], ["12952"], ["14389"], ["14955"], ["16823"]]
[[6556], [9359], [11319], [12952], [14389], [14955], [16823]]
```

I'm trying to compare these two arrays using the - symbol, but am only getting an output of each id, instead of what I expect (nothing) since both arrays contain the same items.

I can see that the first array has quotations around each key inside the bracket.  The second does not.  How do I compare these two arrays?

Comment: `params[:title_ids]` already contains the ids, no need to create a new array (`event_title_ids` in your case).

Comment: Use Array#map to map an array into another instead of iterating and adding manually:  `campaign_title_ids = campaign_titles.map(&:title_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add params as integers to your array

```
params[:title_ids].each do |title|
  event_title_ids << [title.to_i]
end
```